# jw player with rtmp player fullwidth in mobile view

Tags: jwplayer

When i am clicking on full widt button in mobile on that time it's going for a second in full width and then it's come back to normal position. Any one can help me to  shortout this problem. also i am not getting any error .

Thank you

Comment: RTMP is a Flash only protocol, it will not work using a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

RTMP renders in Flash mode and requires Flash for playback. 
    Mobile devices don’t natively support Flash, that is why 
    you are having issues with mobile.

```
Have a look here for more information:
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430349-about-rtmp-streaming
http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/flash/
```